# How to make options default for multiselect attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multiselect-attribute

select attribute programmatically in Magento 2, is there any way to make the options specified in the code as default so that whenever I create a product I don't have to select options manually.

Following is the code that I have used.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'my_custom_attribute_code',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'required' => false,
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'filterable_in_search' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'group' => 'General',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'option' => [
                'values' => [
                    'Left',
                    'Right',
                    'Up',
                    'Down',
                    'All'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

> You need to add   **'default' => 0** property in your code : it means
>   you are giving this value by default so you don'need to add manually

**Try below code :**

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'my_custom_attribute_code',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

Comment: can i use this `'default' => [0,1]` with array ?

Answer (score -1):

you try this

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'my_custom_attribute_code',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

I hop this code helpful for you

Comment: so you added `'default' => 0` , will that make all the options default?